# sorting files in a directory based on numerical index within file-names

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, awk

I have used a for loop in my script like this ...

```
 for var in ipsec_packet*.txt; do
 echo $var
 done
```

**Output**

```
ipsec_packet10.txt
ipsec_packet11.txt
ipsec_packet12.txt
ipsec_packet13.txt
ipsec_packet14.txt
ipsec_packet15.txt
ipsec_packet16.txt
ipsec_packet17.txt
ipsec_packet18.txt
ipsec_packet1.txt
ipsec_packet2.txt
ipsec_packet3.txt
ipsec_packet4.txt
ipsec_packet5.txt
ipsec_packet6.txt
ipsec_packet7.txt
ipsec_packet8.txt
ipsec_packet9.txt
```

but I want them starting from 1 to the largest avaliable (here 18) in sorted order like this ..

```
ipsec_packet1.txt
ipsec_packet2.txt
... 
...
ipsec_packet18.txt
```

I tried `sort -n k14` but it did not help. Please suggest me some variation of sort or any other bash/awk feature which could help me.

Comment: Maybe `awk` is wrong tool for sorting data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `sort` with the `-V` option used for *natural sorting of numbers within text*:

```
for var in `ls ipsec_packet*.txt | sort -V`; do  echo $var; done
```

Comment: my sort (GNU coreutils) 6.10 doesn't have -V

Answer (score 1):

If *GNU sort* is not available (i.e. *-V* isn't supported) and if *Perl* is acceptable:

```
perl -le'
  print join $/, 
    map $_->[1], 
      sort { 
        $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] 
        } map [/(\d+)\./, $_], 
          glob shift
  ' '*.txt'
```

Alternatively:

```
printf '%s\n' *.txt |
  sed 's/.*[^0-9]\([0-9]*\)\./\1,&/' |
    sort -n |
      cut -d, -f2-
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer [codaddict's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210733/sorting-files-in-a-directory-based-on-numerical-index-within-file-names/8210792#8210792), but here is a `sed`+`sort` trick for when your `sort` doesn't have `-V`:

```
for var in $(ls ipsec_packet*.txt | sed 's/[0-9]/\t&/' | sort -n -k2 | sed 's/\t//')
do
    echo $var
done
```

You can replace `\t` with any single character that does not appear in your input data and specify that character as `sort`'s field separator with `-t`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
ls -v ipsec_packet*.txt
```